# How to avoid overlapping of UIImageViews in Touch events?

Tags: objective-c, uitouch

I want to avoid overlapping of two or more UIImageViews through touchesEnded event,
 how to do it???

Answer (score 0):

You can find the intersection of two objects by using [CGRectIntersectsRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

For more info, visit this [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/18/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-part-2-user-interaction-simple-ai-game-logic/)